# ComboBox changes text when dropped down

Tags: c++, mfc, combobox

I have ComboBox (DropDown one) with 2 items in it ("One", "Onion"). When I type 'on' in combo and push dropdown arrow then the text i wrote automatically changes (item "One" is highlighted in list and text changes to "One").

How to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you want it to behave since you don't actually specify, but there are three kinds of ComboBox types: Simple, Dropdown, or Drop List. These each have different behaviors as well. I would suggest you play with the different types first and see if you find what you are looking for. You will find this setting in the properties under Type.

I believe you are currently using Dropdown. Changing it to Drop List should make it so that you can only type something that's in the ComboBox. IE: In your example they can only type One or Onion and it will auto complete to whichever is most similar.